# Typescript errors when using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ionic4

I'm trying to use react useState, useRef hooks with the typescript in Ionic app, and constantly having silly typescript errors when trying to access object properties.

```
const [ matrix, updateMatrix ] = useState([]);
updateMatrix([['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3'], ['cell4', 'cell5', 'cell6']])
```

In the code above I'm getting

**"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"**

```
const basketEl = useRef(null);
if (basketEl.current) { 
  console.log(basketEl.current.getBoundingClientRect())
}
```

In the above code I'm getting **"Object is possibly 'null'"** for basketEl.current. Even if I put

```
if (basketEl.current !== null) {
```

the error still present.
The interesting thing is that if I do not use hooks and use react classes, typescript errors go away. It takes a lot of time to fix ts errors, and I gave up and started to use classes. Maybe I'm using hooks wrong? Do someone have the same problems using hooks and typescript together?

Comment: Why you not typing the hooks when using typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the exact types of the states because they are ambiguous based on the default values.

Correct code:

```
const [ matrix, updateMatrix ] = useState<string[]>([]);

const basketEl = useRef<Element>(null);
```

Comment: for the ref now I have this ts error

`Type 'RefObject<Element>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<Element>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, and 108 more.ts(2322)`
when assign ref `<div id="basket" ref={basketEl}>`

I took example with assigning null from the react website

Comment: Have you tried `useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)`?

Answer (score 0):

`const [ matrix, updateMatrix] = useState<any>([])`
Have you tried this

Answer (score 0):

because the `basketEl` is null, thus you cannot call `basketEl.current`. Firstly, you have to call it in `useEffect` when component did mount. Secondly, the error of typescript, you can fix like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(basketEl !== null && basketEl.current !== null){
     console.log(basketEl.current.getBoundingClientRect())
  }
}, [basketEl])
```

please try it, I am sure it works well